# Handling data request in app, best practice

Tags: ios

I am trying to build a iOS based NEWS app. I went through some of the best NEWS app and found out that, when I tap on any menus like Home(for ex.), they request for home data, only once, next time when i tap Home, I think they display cached data because I don't see any sign of request for data, maintaining speed in app.

So how do they maintain the app with recent data, because every time if cached data is displayed, the data may be already changed in server which may not reflect in the app. So what is the best way to handle data request in apps. Is it like I should request data on every tap of menu buttons or should I maintain some timer to request recent data from the server and rest of the time display cached data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CoreData` for caching the news and store the timestamp as well and before displaying it to the user, check for the timestamp. If the last updated time is older than 'x' minutes, get the data from server.

Also, you can store the last updated time of the news articles on the server and create an API to just return the article IDs and their timestamps. Then in your app, first query for the time stamps, and fetch only those articles which are missing in your DB or with older timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most popular way is to use Great Http libraries like [AFNetwork](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking)
or [ASIHttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

This libraries provide support for caching in the most recommended way.

By setting simple `cachePolicy` you can easily achieve your purpose.

Its not just about caching it can handle many hidden http complexities on its own (cookies,https authentication,Not-Modified http header many more).

I strongly recommend you to use this way as i have already done some of the ios news reading app.