# Permanently change app using server data

Tags: ios, server

In my app there is a TextView that contains a date that is subject to change. Once the app is published on the app store, I want to be able to change the text of the TextView. I see two ways of doing this:

1. Change the text of the actual TextView in the code and resubmit the binary to apple, which takes a few weeks for them to approve, and all the users need to download the updated version (not ideal).
2. Have the app check a server somewhere to see if there is an updated version of the text for the TextView to use. This requires the user to have a constant internet connection (whenever they aren't on the internet connection, the TextView will revert back to its original text because it won't be able to check the server to see if it needs to display different text).

Ideally what I want is a system where the app checks a server for an updated version of the text, and if there is an updated version the TextView permanently takes on that updated version. Thus, as soon as it has been updated once, it will always remain in that updated state regardless of internet connectivity. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Store something on the device, just like you'd store user data. Display it, check for new data, replace if needed.

Comment: Crap, meant to use [Handling data request in app best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21794571)

Comment: Wait so if I set a variable in viewDidLoad() of the main ViewController, will that variable always be set that way (as opposed to being reset each time) whenever the user opens the app as long as they don't delete the app?

Comment: Or do I have to work with "CoreData"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740392/how-to-store-user-data-ios